# SelectRadio Not Working Rerender outputPanel

Tags: rerender, outputpanel, selectradio

[On selecting Yes/No from the selectRadio options, outputPanel reRender is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23886119/1939234)

Here's the code

I have 2 radio buttons.. yes/no. If user clicks Yes, it should display the outputPanel. If No, the outputpanel should hide.  Its simple. But Im missing something. Here's my code.

```
<apex:selectRadio id="selectedAPTransport" value="{!selectedAPTransport}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListAPTransport}"/>                                        
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Travel_block" />
</apex:selectRadio>                                 

<apex:outputPanel id="Travel_block" rendered="{!IF(selectedAPTransport == 'Yes',true,false)}" >
     <apex:repeat id="TravelNeeded" value="{!map}" var="item" > 
     <!-- columns -->                              
     </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Apex class

```
public String selectedAPTransport {get; set;} 

public List<SelectOption> getListAPTransport() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('Yes','Yes')); 
    options.add(new SelectOption('No','No')); 
    return options; 
}

public String getselectedAPTransport() {
    return selectedAPTransport;
}

public void setselectedAPTransport(String selectedAPTransport) {    
    this.selectedAPTransport = selectedAPTransport; 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `apex:outputPanel` with `id="Travel_block"` is not rendered by default, because the `selectedAPTransport` variable is not `Yes`. If it is not rendered, then it is not accessible by ID for `actionSupport`. You need to wrap this pannel with another panel without layout and rerender it (`wrapperPannel` in my example):

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedAPTransport}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListAPTransport}"/>                                        
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="wrapperPannel" />
</apex:selectRadio>                                 

<apex:outputPanel id="wrapperPannel" layout="none">
    <apex:outputPanel id="Travel_block" rendered="{!IF(selectedAPTransport == 'Yes',true,false)}" >
        <apex:repeat value="{!mapApplicantProduct['Travel']}" var="item" >                                  
          <apex:inputCheckbox id="Selected" value="{!item.selected}" required="True"/>
          <apex:outputText id="ApplicantProduct_Description" value="{!item.applicantProduct.Description__c}"/>    
     </apex:repeat>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It did indeed work.  Now the problem is, after the outputPanel becomes visible, the required="true" condition doesn't work for the inputCheckbox.

Comment: @BruceLee It is a next question bro :)

Comment: haha.. Do I need to create a new one? :)